# What's the proper way to have a default value only for CREATE view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to have a default value for my model attribute:

_form.blade.php code: `{!! Form::text('attribute','Default Value') !!}`

As `_form.blade.php` is shared for both `create.blade.php` and `edit.blade.php`, both views are always displaying the default value: `Default Value`.

What's the properly way to have a default value only for CREATE view?
So EDIT view should always display the value of the saved model.

---

It seems like a dumb question, but I'm a long time puzzling over this and I would like to know the properly way to do that. 
I have some ideas, such as:

- Do not use a shared file for create/edit (_form.blade.php) (I think it's not a good idea).
- Set the default variable in the controller (also not good).

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::text('name', (isset($savedModel)) ? $savedModel->name : "your default value") !!}
```

I haven't tried a ternary inside a `Form` facade element, but it may work.

Comment: I believe I have expressed myself badly. The problem is not a default value dynamic, It's because it's also displaying the default value in EDIT form, where it should display the value of the saved model.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento, I believe the update should handle this for you. Check for the saved model. If that is set, then display the name, otherwise, show the default.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is this:

```
<input name="field" value="{{ old('field', isset($model->field) ? $model->field : '') }}"/>
```

Here's the breakdown:

- If they edited/saved(first time) the form and the save failed, but was `back()->withErrors()`, this value will be used.
- If they just invoked the "edit" view with no changes, the `$model->field` will be used.
- If they are creating the model but have not attempted a save yet, no value will be used. (`''`)

This should cover all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it's typically better not to share views between create/edit operations. You run into a lot of conditional logic that can be avoided and you get a cleaner user experience when displaying form errors and such.

As far as displaying a default value for the Create view, I use the `old('attribute', 'Default Value')` helper method to achieve this.